# Memoizing methods in frozen objects

Tags: ruby

I'm working with an abstract syntax tree, where each vertex is a subclass of a `Node` class. This base class is defined in a third party library, and the `Node` objects are frozen upon construction.

Now I'm performing some expensive operations that traverse the tree, sometimes recursively, and would like to memoize the result of those. Below is an example of such a subclass, and operation result being memoized using the "classic" Ruby pattern:

```
class DefNode < Node
  def visibility_scope
    @visibility_scope ||= VisibilityScopeResolver.new(self).resolve
  end
end
```

However, since the `Node` constructor freezes the object, trying to assign to an instance variable results in an error:

```
DefNode.new(children).visibility_scope
#=> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen DefNode
```

Is there a way to (idiomatially) perform memoization in frozen objects? Ideally without overriding the constructor in each subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is declare a `private` writer, which allows conditionally setting the value, even in a frozen object:

```
class DefNode < Node
  def visibility_scope
    resolved_visibility_scope ||= VisibilityScopeResolver.new(self).resolve
  end

  private

  attr_writer :resolved_visibility_scope
end
```

I went with this solution because it allows the state to be contained in the instance itself, which is slightly easier to reason about, and won't have any unforeseen side effects. One downside of this is that, at first glance, it doesn't quite look like the familiar "rose memoization" pattern.

It is worth noting that the writer could also be named `visibility_scope`, since it only defines `#visibility_scope=`, and thus doesn't conflict with the manually defined reader. I opted to give it a distinct name, however, to minimise the potential for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about “idiomatic,” but when I have been there, I used a hash on the class itself:

```
class DefNode < Node
  def self.visibility_scopes
    @visibility_scopes ||= {}
  end

  def visibility_scope
    self.class.visibility_scopes[__id__] ||=
      VisibilityScopeResolver.new(self).resolve
  end
end
```